# Manipulating Excel with Python

Tags: python, excel

I am new to Py. I need to write data to, read data from, and run a few VBA macros within an excel book. Would rather the book never be opened (non-graphical), but I'll take a "remote control" approach if that's what it takes. I installed [Openpyxl](https://pypi.org/project/openpyxl/#files) and tried to load in the complicated xlsm book, and it complained "Data Validation Extension" is not supported. I was able to read a value from a cell anyway, but not able to write a new value into a cell. And when i saved the new book, it was half the size it should be, and excel couldn't open it due to it being "corrupt".

Is there a more robust way to do this? Maybe i just need a couple load options?

I used: `wb = load_workbook(filename = 'myBook.xlsm')`

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use pandas lib- https://pandas.pydata.org/
import the library-

import pandas as pd

data_frame = pd.read_excel("myBook.xlsm")

pandas has lots of helpful methods.
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

Comment: Can we operate the natural VBA scripts within the excel, using Panda?